# How to use broswer cookies/hash real-time in a broswer and client using node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, cookies, socket.io

I developing a project where I need to use in my client app (running in Linux) cookies that are being used by the broswer (that it also running by the client user).

So I'm trying to use node.js (and probably socket.io together) to do it. But every solution I try works for only one cookie. That is, I can extract the cookie information but once I do it when I change everything in my broswer (hence changing its cookies) it wont reflect in my app. So I would need such a thing like a real time cookie parsing.

I've tryed it using 'cookies.js' and also casper.js (definitively not what I'm looking for)

Is possible to do it with node.js? How should I procide to reach it?

Comment: Sounds like a misuse of cookies. What prevents you from keeping an in memory model of your state? There are also frameworks supporting real time db sync such as firebase and meteor and to some extent Parse-server. If that is your use case.

Comment: Thank you so much! I figured out what I was doing wrong and in fact I was misusing cookies. Thank you for the suggestions. I will try it.